# Black screen when running most games fullscreen

Tags: pc, technical-issues

So I'm coming with my head in my hands asking for somebody to help me out with my laptop.

My basic system information is as follows: http://pastebin.com/AVeGH8j6

This is only a problem I have experienced in the past few months. Basically, 90% of my games will not run in fullscreen. When I load them up, I merely get a black screen (with game audio as normal). Games that let me move to windowed using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then work fine in windowed mode (once I've played around a bit, as my laptop usually locks up upon game launch; I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then use the sleep button and load it back up to get it to respond). So if I can get them to run in windowed mode or borderless fullscreen windowed, they work fine.

Initially, I assumed it was a driver problem, so, I uninstalled my current NVidia drivers, used an online guide to delete all traces of them as suggested, then updated to the latest ones to no avail. I have even tried backdating my drivers to the ones that came preloaded. Nothing has worked. At the moment I am running the latest drivers for my GT555M (310.70) and I am still having the same problem.

I also heard it might be something to do with Avast! (my antivirus), so I uninstalled it and tried again - nothing.

Hours of trawling Google has yielded little - it's a major headache for a committed PC gamer!
N.B. some of my techy friends have suggested formatting my hard drive or reinstalling my OS, but my recovery disk was made pre-installation of SP1, which I heard makes it effectively useless, and on top of that I'd rather not lose a load of my single user licenses (e.g. MS Office). What could I do to fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried Java?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - Java is fully updated on my computer but  don't see how it'd help :(

Comment: Have you taken a look through your process list to see if there are any other programs that might be interrupting your graphics adapters?  Maybe try running the games with the machine in safe mode, just as a test.

Comment: this usually means the wrong resolution is being used

Comment: @Tom was just a thought.

Comment: does your machine have optimus by any chance?

Comment: Yes spartacus, it uses optimus. Just looking - my laptop seems now to auto select integrated card for everything, even if I apply settings in nvidia control panel to auto select dedicated. However, even telling an individual game to run using the dedicated card, and it running with that card doesn't seem to solve it :(

Comment: @Tom I suspect something weird is going on with optimus, but I don't know what exactly.  All I know is I've heard lots of bad things with the GT555m card and optimus.

Comment: [This link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96764/black-screen-when-running-most-games-fullscreen#comment132472_96764) suggests forcing the GT555m to run by plugging the display into a HDMI port (if your machine has one).

Comment: whoops, wrong link :P: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/507703/gt555m-optimus-trouble-33-it-sucks-that-i-know-i-39-m-not-the-only-victim-/

Comment: Thanks for the link - unfortunately I left my HDMI cable at uni, but  think I've become so sick of it I'm going to reformat my hard drive and hope it sorts it for me.

Comment: @Tom I don't think that'll help.  This definitely sounds like an optimus issue.  Even though it may seem like your game is using the 555m it may not be.  You have to figure out a way to force the 555m to be turned on.  If you have a hdmi ready display, you can run down to a local best buy or staples and pick up a cheap hdmi cable (don't pay more than 10$)

Comment: Hey spartacus, you're right, I reckon that's exactly what it was, but seeing as optimus was working correctly up until the past few months, I did the reformatting and it now functions correctly. I think there must have been some kind of driver/software issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have a GT 540M chipset with 314.07 drivers and have encountered this issue as well. Anytime I run any game full-screen, the display becomes completely unresponsive and I have to put my laptop in standby mode to minimize it.

I discovered that turning V-sync on through the game config files or by forcing V-sync on through the nVidia Control Panel fixes this issue.

I have no idea why this works or if there is a way to run full-screen games without V-sync.

I hope this helps!  :)